# GetAsyncKeyState's return values don't seem to correspond with the description

Tags: c++, binary, hex, return-value, msdn

I investigated [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after seeing it in a code example on how to make a fictional character move on the screen through the WASD keys.

I read this on its MSDN page:

> **Return value**
>
> Type: *SHORT*
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key
> was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the
> key is currently up or down.
>
> *If the most significant bit is set, the
> key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was
> pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.*

I'm having trouble understanding the structure of the return value:

It says the type is `short`, so through it I suppose you could represent the number zero, in binary, as `0000000000000000`, or in hex as `0x0000` (since as far as I know one hex digit represents four binary digits).

The description says that the *most significant bit* should be set when the key is pressed. That makes me think that, if said bit was set, the number would appear like this:

```
1000000000000000
```

To make better use of it in my program, I shortened it by translating it to hex, resulting into:

```
0x8000
```

Because `8` in hex should correspond to `1000` in binary.

When I saw that said mechanism was not working in my program (doing `GetAsyncKeyState(chr) == 0x8000` would always yield false, no matter if the key was pressed or not) I took one more look to the original example I saw the function employed in first. There, the return value was being compared with the number `-32767`, which, when quickly translated to hex using the Windows calculator, results into the value `0xFFFFFFFFFFFF8001`. Now, don't mind the last hex digit (1) because that's the bit used to check whether the least significant bit is also active, but I don't want that in my case.

The things that I can't understand here are the following:

1. Why, if one hex digit represents four binary digits, and the output value of the function is a short (two bytes), here the number is represented by sixteen hex digits? Aren't those eight bytes?
2. The description of the return value said that the *most significant bit* would be set to 1 if the key was being pressed, and that led me to believe that the number would look like `1000000000000000`, not `0000000000001000`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GetAsyncKeyState(chr) == 0x8000
```

This is incorrect check. Use:

```
!!(GetAsyncKeyState(chr) & 0x8000)
```

to see if the most-significant bit is set.

The value `0xFFFFFFFFFFFF8001` doesn't correspond to the actual returned value from GetAsyncKeyState. Windows calculator doesn't know the size of the value returned from GetAsyncKeyState, so it assumes you're working with 64-bit number. You can override it in its settings.

Comment: What does !! before the expression do?

Comment: @GabrieleCirulli: it's the shortest way to convert it to bool. Equivalent in this context to: `(GetAsyncKeyState(chr) & 0x8000) != 0`

Comment: The return value is getting signed extended since it's a short, so 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF8001 is the correct 64-bit representation.

Answer (score 3):

1 - returned value is `SHORT`, which is 16 bits = 2 bytes.

2 - most significant bit is the 15th, as the value is signed if you cast it to 32-bit `INT`, 16-bit `1000 0000` value would become `1111 1111 1000 0000` (in 64-bit world the conversion would be `1000 0000` -> `1111 1111 1111 1111 - 1111 1111 1000 0000`). If you want to just test the most significant bit of the signed integer value, just compare it to zero:

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(...) < 0)
{
  // Hey, MSB is set here!
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me the logical reason why comparing it to 0 would result into checking the most significant bit?

Comment: Because signed negative integers always have most significant bit set, and positives have it unset. Zero has all bits equal to zero. Comparison to zero is a smart way to test the MSB.